# System of equations to represent a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose that there is a $n \times n$ matrix. Then there will be entries $A_{ij}$ where i and j represent row and column.

Equations contain entries of a matrix, $A_{ij}$ and when the equations are solved, we will get each entry.
(Add: By equations I mean like ${A_{11}}^2 + {A_{12}}^3+..$ where $A_{ij}$ would be entries of a matrix.)

Is there any way to represent the matrix using a system of only $kn$ equations where $k$ is constant for all combinations of integer entries? (Obviously, linear equations will not do this.)

Any variation of the matrix is allowed if the variation respect the following: entries ($n \times n$ of them) in the same column and row must be in the same column and row.

Edit:
In linear algebra, for example, if there are $n \times n$ distinct equations, then you will be able to get entries of a matrix. This is a-bit different question.

Comment: What do you mean by "represent the matrix using a system of only $kn$ equations"? What is $k$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan constant.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by representing the matrix using a system of equations?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Equations contain components of a matrix, $A_{ij}$ and when the equations are solved, we will get each component. And as the question says.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: What is an $n \times n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan By equations I mean like ${A_{11}}^2 + {A_{12}}^3+..$ where $A_{ij}$ wpuld be components of a matrix.

Comment: @Liz: I still don't understand what you're asking. What is the relevance of the fact that you've put the $A_{ij}$ into a matrix? What do you want these equations to do?

Comment: Okay. Let me get this right. You would like to represent an $n\times n$ matrix $A,$ by $n^2$ variables, $A_{ij}$ denoting the $n^2$ **entries** (not components) of $A.$ Then, are you looking for equations involving the $A_{ij}$'s? What is given (or, known) here?

Comment: @J.D. My mistake. I was unsure of which tags I should use. The optimization tag would not be something that describes my problem..

Comment: @J.D. yes, I am refering to entries. And yes, I am looking for equations involving the entries. What I am asking is when given any matrix of $n \times n$ entries, can we define one system of $kn$ equations that will be able to represent the matrix (and works for any matrix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This isn't really an answer, just a too long for a comment. I'll repeat myself here to make sure I understood you correctly..*

Let the variables $A_{ij}, 1 \le i,j \le n$ denote the $(i,j)$th entry of the $n\times n$ matrix $A.$ Given such an $A,$ you would like to *encode* it as a system of polynomials: $$P_i(A_{11}, A_{12}, \ldots, A_{nn}) = 0, \quad 1 \le i \le B, \tag{1}$$ where $B$ is the total number of polynomial equations. The system $(1)$ is constructed from the entries of $A,$ and the solution to $(1)$ *uniquely* determines $A.$ Your question is then about how small $B$ could be? In particular, could $B = kn$ for some constant $k$?

Obviously, if $\text{deg}(P_i) = 1$ for all $i,$ i.e. a linear system, then we need $n^2$ such equations.

If $\text{deg}(P_i) = d_i > 1,$ for some (or all) $i,$ then the situation doesn't get better. Consider the situation with only 2 variables. Two lines can uniquely determine a point, because the number of intersection points is at most 1. Now consider a higher degree curve: circles ($x^2 + y^2 - c = 0$.) Two circles intersect in at most 2 points, which gives you 2 solutions, one of which is your *original* matrix $A,$ and the other is some other matrix similar (as far as conditions go) to your original matrix. In higher dimensions (i.e. more variables), polynomials become surfaces & intersections become curves.

In general, the number of common solutions will be proportional to the product of the degrees, by [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem). Alas, I'm not well familiar with algebraic geometry, and other user will prove far more helpful.

*Again, long comment really rather than answer.*

Comment: Oh. That's why linear algebra is most commonly used, right?

Comment: What about limiting the case to integers (entries)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I know precisely what you are looking for. However, the following may give a partial answer.

Suppose that we are working over the **reals**. Then the system of $m$ simultaneous equations 
$$P_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0, \quad P_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0,\dots\dots, \quad P_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$$
 is equivalent to the **single** equation 
$$\left(P_1^2(x_1,\dots,x_n)+ P_2^2(x_1,\dots,x_n)+\cdots+P_m^2(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)=0.$$